# Hidden detail panel in TortoiseHg

Tags: tortoisehg

My detail panel is hidden in TortoiseHg 2.0.4. I have tried looking at the options in view and tried selecting various options like "Revision Details" or "Commit", but nothing shows up. How can I make it appear again?

[image]

(Screenshot has had details erased)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your window is just hidden Try hovering mouse on the space above Output Log and than pull it up once cursor changes. Check out my mock-up:

[image: How to pull window.]